# How do I elevate permissions to access memory in a memory editor?

Tags: c++, winapi

I’m trying to make a memory editor that requires me to elevate permissions of my program. I’ve looked all around the wide web, and haven’t found a single result on what I need. I need: code that can elevate my program so it can edit/have access to the memory of a Windows-protected process (such as lsass.exe or svchost.exe). I know that I do in fact need to escalate my permissions as after attempting to `WriteProcessMemory()` and use `GetLastError()`, I get error code 998 (ERROR_NO_ACCESS).

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thank you.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/604927/how-do-i-configure-my-application-to-run-as-administrator-automatically

Comment: You can't elevate your program after it starts running. The user has to choose to elevate it when starting it. You can add a manifest to force that prompt. Otherwise, your program will have to spawn a second process or COM object that runs elevated.

Comment: What's kind of access do you want to do on Windows-protected process memory and why? [Protected Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights#protected-processes), [Protecting Anti-Malware Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/protecting-anti-malware-services-).

Comment: I am running my program as administrator, and still no good. I’m trying to edit the memory of a Windows protected process, and I know it is possible; I just don’t know how I can achieve it.

Comment: @EpicDreamzPlays but WHY do you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Protected processes are protected for a reason.

Comment: I’n trying to edit the memory of a protected process, it’s for nothing malicious...

Comment: I'm pretty sure my answer solves your question, if you need more advice on this let me know and I will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 parts to this question:

- Running as admin
- Writing to protected memory
- Privileges required for writing to lsass.exe

To force a program to run as administrator you just need to add a manifest file which you can do like so:
[image: How to add Manifest File Run as Admin]

If you want to write to a memory page which does not have write permissions you need to use [VirtualProtectEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotectex) I use it in a wrapper like this:

```C++
PatchEx(HANDLE hProcess, char* dst, char* src, int size)
{
    DWORD oldprotect;
    VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, dst, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldprotect);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, dst, src, size, NULL);
    VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, dst, size, oldprotect, &oldprotect);
}
```

As part of Windows security, you cannot edit memory of processes running as SYSTEM which lsass.exe does.

In order to edit lsass.exe you will need to at a bare minimum also be running as SYSTEM by grabbing a SYSTEM token.  But since Windows 8.1 lsass.exe is a Protected Process Light (PPL) process, therefore it is no longer that easy.

You can read more about it on [Alex Ionescu's Blog](http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=97)

You will most likely need to be in kernel mode to mess with LSASS.

Answer (score 0):

ERROR_NO_ACCESS is different from ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. If this memory is set read-only you need to change the permission of it. ([VirtualProtectEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotectex))

Refer to "[How is it that WriteProcessMemory succeeds in writing to read-only memory?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20181206-00/?p=100415)".

One possibility is access it from a protected process that [require signed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/protecting-anti-malware-services-#requirements) with valid certificates.